# JMeter delays takes longer than they should

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter in order to test some environment. I build a thread group in JMeter that includes a couple of https requests with a delay between each of them.


somthing like this:
1.  https request
2. random delay
3. https requst
4. random delay
6. https requst
7. random delay.


But for some reason the delays take much longer than they should and the test take much longer than it should (a delay of only 3 seconds or 3000 milliseconds takes 13 minutes). I try switching the random delays to constant ones but it still takes longer.

I tried searching online for a reason but I couldn't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the delay **level under** the request so it will impact only a single request,

Currently each delay affecting all the requests in the same level and that is causing the inconsistency

See [JMeter's execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of is that your test setup violates [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/)

If you design your test like this:

[image]

All 3 [timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) will be executed **before each request** so instead of 3 seconds of waiting time after sampler you will get 9 seconds of waiting time **before each sampler**

- If you want to apply a random delay before each sampler - leave only one timer.
- If you want to apply different delays before each sampler - make timers children of the respective samplers:

  [image]
- If you want delay after the sampler instead of before the sampler - use [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler instead of timer

Comment: Yes, thank you, I designed the test wrong, now I changed it and it solved the problem.